# How to pass Dropdown list ID to grid and load multiple grid in angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, grid

I am trying to pass dropdown list ID to multiple grids in one page.

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp.ctrls')
    .controller('Ctrl_Maps', function ($scope, $http) {
....
    $scope.itemChanged = function () {
            CountryGEOGrid();
        };


        function CountryGEOGrid(){

            $http.get()
                .success(function (data) {
...
                });
        }
    });
```

i want to pass the ID to this grid

```
angular.module('myApp.ctrls')
    .controller('Ctrl_ActualIssueByRegion', function($scope, reportService) {
        $scope.ActualIssueByRegionGridOptions = {}
}
...
```

how i can i link this two controllers ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use service for setting and getting a value from two different controllers.

my factory for setting and getting a value

for example:

```
app.factory('MainService', function() {
  var itemProd = [];
  return {
    setProd: function(item) {
      itemProd.push(item);
      console.log(itemProd);
    },
    getProd: function() {
      return itemProd;
    }
  }
});
```

just the same with you, all you need to do was to pass the ID and call the setter function, then if you need to get the id just use the getter.

if you need the full code here is my fiddle "http://plnkr.co/edit/hvxI2ABmMBR6bNyKViFC?p=preview"